# Automatic reduce time By record Wise in Data Table using C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have one `DataTable` in code. the `Datatable` has three columns named 1-**`ID`** , 2-**`Tag`** , 3-**`Time`** as shown below. Here when ever I add one record to `Datatable` , I set the `Time` to 180 Sec for that record. Here I want to reduce that time automatically by record wise. See below Example to understand .

In Data Table I have :

```
ID     Tag       Time

1     TS009      180 Seconds
```

this record after 15 seconds :

```
ID     Tag       Time

1     TS009     165 Sec
```

Now I add one more row as below :

```
2     TS010     180 Sec
```

Now I have 2 records in DataTable :

```
ID     Tag       Time

1    TS009    165 Sec

2    TS010    180 Sec
```

again , after 10 Sec My `Datatable` has :

```
1    TS009    155 Sec

2    TS010    170 Sec
```

Friends please help me out with this problem .

Comment: What's the type of `Time`??

Comment: maybe Timer will work for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: Hi Ahmed, its like timer control .

Comment: @AravindGarre I've added a solution for your problem , please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve your goal by using a `Timer`

by using a timer I'm gonna reduce All data's Time in `dataTable` every 1 second so we're gonna loop through the data and reduce every single of them .

My `dataTable` Implementation :

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Tag");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Time");
```

adding a timer to the form in the constructor :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

and Finally the timer Event Handler :

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = dataTable.Rows.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        int time;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            time = Convert.ToInt16(dataTable.Rows[i][2]);
            if (time > 0)
                dataTable.Rows[i][2] = time - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)